# How do I make IIS compress .svg files?

Tags: iis, optimization, compression, gzip

I'm trying to acomplish this in web.config:

```
<staticContent>
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml" />
</staticContent>
<httpCompression>
    <staticTypes>
        <add mimeType="image/svg+xml" enabled="true"/>
    </staticTypes>
</httpCompression>
<urlCompression doStaticCompression="true" doDynamicCompression="true"/>
```

But `Content-Encoding: gzip` never appears in response headers. Though, compression works good for other types like CSS.

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [can't get iis7 to gzip font-face font files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14410331/cant-get-iis7-to-gzip-font-face-font-files)

Answer (score 5):

@Dominique Alexandre points to a solution that shows how you can edit the applicationHost.config file, which works just fine.

I just wanted to add how you can do this using the IIS Manager GUI.

Go to IIS Manager > YOUR_SERVER > Under Management section > Configuration Editor > Expand the system.webServer > httpCompression > dynamicTypes

And then add the mime types you want to be compressed additionally.

Comment: Dominique's answer has since been deleted.  However, the key part of Dominique's answer was to point users towards [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14410331/cant-get-iis7-to-gzip-font-face-font-files/23940235#23940235) instead, which can be adapted to fit the question.

Answer (score 3):

You need to turn it on for SVGs in IIS as a lower level. This post has the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23940235/15233

Comment: this link got the answer!

Answer (score 1):

In my case, `image/svg+xml` was already listed as a mime type under `<staticTypes>` but it still wasn't working. On a whim I also added the mime type to `<dynamicTypes>` and that solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the mime-type is really not nice.

See this post instead on how to implement a custom httpmodule which does the gzipping for you in a few lines of code.

http://laubplusco.net/gzip-svg-files-asp-net/

Answer (score -2):

**Not relevant, see Dominique Alexandre solution**

OK, no one has answer. So I'll post here my temporary workaround.

I changed the mime type to text/xml, so it gets GZipped by IIS:

```
<mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="text/xml" />
```

Comment: Do the svg files render correctly in the browser? Compression works but this is causing the svg files to not render at all for me.

Comment: How about if the file is of type image(jpeg)