# Enable compression fontawesome-webfont.svg

Tags: asp.net, iis, svg, compression, pagespeed

I am always getting RED mark "enable compression for fontawesome-webfont.svg"
 on https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/

Compressing resources with gzip or deflate can reduce the number of bytes sent over the network.
Enable compression for the following resources to reduce their transfer size by 175KiB (70% reduction).
Compressing /fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.0.3 could save 175KiB (70% reduction).

I already did IIS provided compression options:
Static files only
Dynamic application responses only
Both static files and dynamic application responses

Answer (score 1):

By default, IIS doesn't map the MIME type for SVGs. You will have to update your Web.config to include the correct mappings for SVGs like so:

```
<system.webServer>
       <httpCompression directory="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\temp\IIS Temporary Compressed Files">
           <scheme name="gzip" dll="%Windir%\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll" />
               <staticTypes>
                <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
                <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" />
                <add mimeType="application/x-javascript" enabled="true" />
                <add mimeType="application/atom+xml" enabled="true" />
                <add mimeType="application/xaml+xml" enabled="true" />
                <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />

                <!-- HERE -->
                <add mimeType="image/svg+xml" enabled="true" />
                <add mimeType="application/font-woff" enabled="true" />
                <add mimeType="application/x-font-ttf" enabled="true" />
                <add mimeType="application/octet-stream" enabled="true" />
                <!-- HERE -->

            </staticTypes>
      </httpCompression>
  <urlCompression doStaticCompression="true" doDynamicCompression="true"/>
</system.webServer>
```

For more details on this, check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14410331/cant-get-iis7-to-gzip-font-face-font-files/23940235#23940235). To test whether compression is working or not, use the [Chrome Developer Tools](http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/) and check the HTTP response header contains the following:

```
Content-Encoding: gzip
```