# Enable Compression Mime-types for Web-Site Application

Tags: iis, http-compression

Our website uses both dynamic and static compression. I know that compression can be enabled/disabled on a web.config level, but that the mime-types for static and dynamic compression cannot be enabled at a web-config level.

Meaning, this section:

```
<httpCompression directory="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\temp\IIS Temporary Compressed Files" staticCompressionIgnoreHitFrequency="true">
    <scheme name="gzip" dll="%Windir%\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll" />
    <staticTypes>
        Stuff
    </staticTypes>
    <dynamicTypes>
        Stuff
    </dynamicTypes>
</httpCompression>
```

Must go in the applicationHost.config, and is generally edited using appcmd.exe.

I know there is a `location` element in the applicationHost.config that allows setting many things on a per website basis, but I can't seem to find anywhere if mimetypes for dynamic compression are one of them.

I have tried overriding these settings using a location element, but have not had any success and cannot find documentation stating it's possible for the `httpCompression` element.

To make matters worse, we install our product as a web application under the default site, so really we want to enable these dynamic compression mime-types only under our application, instead of site (or server) wide. Is this possible?

Generally, we are using IIS 7 and above. Right now our minimum is 7, so assume anything needs to work with that.

My question is:

Can `httpCompression` settings be set in the applicationHost.config per website and possible per web application under a web site?

Is there a different way to enable dynamicCompression specifics on a website/web application level?

Answer (score 2):

Just an important precision: There is one prerequisite to ensure that you can add MIME Types in the **"web.config"** file:

It is possible to add MIME Types in the *<staticTypes>* and *<dynamicTypes>* sections at the website level (in **"web.config"**) **only if this is explicitely allowed** at the **"applicationHost.config"** level, as explained in [this solution from Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29083557/3487940):

> The important thing to note is that modifying your
>   **applicationHost.config** (in %windir%\system32\inetsrv\config) from the following setting:
>
> ```
> <section name="httpCompression" allowDefinition="AppHostOnly" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
> ```
>
> to:
>
> ```
> <section name="httpCompression" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
> ```
>
> will enable configuration of the httpCompression tag under the
>   system.webServer tag in your **web.config**.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can very well add dynamic and static types in web application's web.config file. ApplicationHost.config will define global compression settings and if you want to override them in your application you can do so. Following is sample from one of my application.

```
<system.webServer>
<modules>
  <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
  <add name="Glimpse" type="Glimpse.AspNet.HttpModule, Glimpse.AspNet" preCondition="integratedMode" />
  <remove name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" />
  <add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" />
</modules>
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
<handlers>
  <add name="Glimpse" path="glimpse.axd" verb="GET" type="Glimpse.AspNet.HttpHandler, Glimpse.AspNet" preCondition="integratedMode" />
</handlers>
    <httpCompression>
        <dynamicTypes>
            <remove mimeType="text/*" />
            <add mimeType="application/json" enabled="true" />
        </dynamicTypes>
    </httpCompression>
```

1. Here remove tag in dynamicTypes removes global entry coming from ApplicationHost.config
2. add tag is adding additional mimeType on top of global entries from applicationHost.config. This addition will be applicable only for whose web.config is being modified.

Similarly you can modify staticTypes as well.

Comment: Are you certain it's actually enabled based on these settings? I ask based on two things: 1. this link https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/969062 states that mime types can be added at the web server level only. 2. I tried adding what you have above and it did not work.